# Spring Connecting elements to a main Object within a Collection

Tags: java, forms, spring, collections

Let's say we have 4 Objects:

**GarbageCan :**

- `Long : id`
- `String : name`
- `int : height`
- `Collection<Garbage> : filth`

**Garbage :**

- `Item : item`
- `GarbageType : type`

**Item :**

- `Long : id`
- `String : name`

**GarbageType :**

- `String : type`
- `int : recyclingCategory`

---

Now lets say we retrieve a `collection` of `Item` from our db, We make a selection of which we want to add to our `Garbage` object So we end up with a `Collection` of our selected "`Item`"s.

Then we have to send this `Collection<Item> selectedItems` to our model. We also send a `AutoPopulatedList<Garbage>` to our model. (this is where the filled in data will be saved)

In our view we want to connect the `GarbageType` data (which the user fills in) with the corresponding Item in the `AutoPopulatedList<Garbage>` Collection.

But sadly I have no idea how to do the this last step (the connection), since it is very important that the `GarbageType` is connected with its corresponding `Item`

## We want to:

[image]

My problem is the Second Arrow (the one facing down).

Comment: That typically done by creating a separate class. For instance having a class `TypedGarbageItem` which will connect the item to it's garbage type.

Comment: Just saw you already have such a class:`Garbage`.

Comment: But doesn't Garbage already have the connection between Item and GarbageType ? Also, then i'd still be stuck with the problem that you have to fill a Collection

Comment: I don't understand your problem with filling the collection. In what context?

Comment: For example, if you want to write a view where All the selected  Item's are printed. And you want to user to add the GarbageType data to each selection so you can (at the end) all the selection of Garbage (selected Items and inputted GarbageType's) into a GarbageCan.

Comment: That is quite a broad topic with no simple answer. Typically you create a form backing object which will hold a `Collection<Garbage>` of (to be) selected items.

Comment: I added an image of what i mean, I understand the most of it but i'm stuck on how you have to get all the data into the Collection. Getting the data to to view is no problem, getting the input from the user connecting it to its coresponding Garbage with its coresponding Item and sending that back as a collection of Garbage to my controller is where i'm stuck